# Returning data back to client from Go HTTP request

Tags: go

I've written a simple Fetch Go function which calls an API, and generates a response.

When called, it successfully logs the data to the console which is pulled from the API.

What I want to do though is take the final 'respBody' variable generated from reading the response body, and then return it back to my frontend client - but I can't figure out how.

All the examples just use Println, and I've searched the docs but can't find anything.

Can anyone tell me how to change my code so I can return the respBody back to the client?

Here's my function:

```
func Fetch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending request to server")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(respBody)) // This is the final bit where I want to send this back to the client.

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is a [`HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc), which contains the `ResponseWriter` interface, in your case it's `w`.

---

So, you can write data using `http.ResponseWriter`:

```
func Fetch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending request to server")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    

    // Here:
    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    w.Write(respBody)
}
```

You can use use `io.Copy(w, resp.Body)` instead, remember to close body using `defer resp.Body.Close()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply copy the contents of the response body to the response writer:

```
io.Copy(w,resp.Body)
```

Since you can only read the body once, the solution above will not allow you to get the body. If you also want to log it, or process it somehow, you can read it and then write it to the response writer.

```
respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println(string(respBody)) 
w.Write(respBody)
```